# PublishSubject does not work with firstOrError()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

Can someone please explain me why `PublishSubject` is not working nicely with `firstOrError()`?

I'm expecting `firstOrError` to return a `NoSuchElementException` when the `PublishSubject` is created without any value.

I wrote some tests in order to better explain the problem:

```
@Test
fun `test one`() {
    // THIS TEST FAILS
    val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()

    val testSubscriber = publishSubject
        // .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST) // With or without this doesn't make any difference
        .firstOrError()
        .test()

    testSubscriber
        .assertNotComplete()
        .assertError(NoSuchElementException::class.java)
}

@Test
fun `test two`() {
    // THIS TEST PASSES
    val flowable = Flowable.empty<Boolean>()

    val testSubscriber = flowable
        .firstOrError()
        .test()

    testSubscriber
        .assertNotComplete()
        .assertError(NoSuchElementException::class.java)
}
```

Comment: "test two" has a timing problem. Because you use `onNext()` before the subscription, you won't see the value `true`.

Comment: Fair enough, you're right, i'll remove that example cause is just misleading, i mainly care about the empty scenario. What about the other one?

Comment: In "test one", `publishSubject` never completes, so the `firstOrError()` cannot properly decide anything.

Comment: Mmm doesn't make much sense.. anyway if that's the case what is the way to achieve the same thing? Get the first item or an error if not there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: **`Flowable` emits no element and completes whereas `PublishSubject` emits no element and doesn't complete**.

Long version:

You assume that `PublishSubject.create<Boolean>()` is equivalent to `Flowable.empty<Boolean>()`. But they are not.

First, let's see what [`firstOrError()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#firstOrError--) really does:

> Returns a Single that emits only the very first item emitted by this Observable or signals a NoSuchElementException if this Observable is empty.

So you it makes sense that `Flowable.empty<Boolean>()` works, because it's, well, empty. What does it mean ["empty"](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#empty--)?

> Returns a Flowable that emits no items to the Subscriber and immediately **invokes its onComplete method.**

I emphasized important fragment. `Flowable.empty()` calls `onComplete` whereas `PublishSubject.create()` just creates `Subject` which waits for calling `onNext()` on him or for subscribers.

So `Flowable.empty()` is empty, but `PublishSubject.create()` is not empty. **It doesn't call `onComplete`.** See [PublishSubject docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) for more info.

If you want to have empty `PublishSubject`, simply call `PublishSubject.empty<Boolean>()`.

Comment: The v2 [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html) docs is more elaborate. Besides, `PublishSubject.empty()` is **not** a `PublishSubject` but an `Observable` because `empty()` is a static method on `Observable` visible on all subclasses and can't be overridden.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation of the difference, that really helped. So is it correct to say that the firstOrError() will never work until the PublishSubject calls onComplete or onNext?

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd, your input is always valuable. I update link to docs, it's weird that "default" docs (as you could assume from the link) are for older version. I agree with your point on `empty()` but do you think it makes practical difference or you just wanted to be precise about naming?

Comment: We have canonical links setup in the 1.x javadocs but search engines are not required to follow it when building their indexes. Thus, PublishSubject shows up with the 1.x docs first and 2.x is only the second. There were confusion about such static methods on subjects; some really did expect they return a subject.